# encode html in php and decode in javascript

Tags: php

I have some html code I want to store in a database. I need a way to encode it in php so all the special characters don't break the db INSERT (the html can include all sorts of spec chars) and then a way to unencode that at the other end in javascript once i've passed it via JSON so that the html is rendered correctly.

IS there any way I can do this?

Comment: Aren't the single and double quotes already escaped in the database?

Comment: @simnom — they should be escaped *for* the database (preferably with PDO since PHP is in use). The act of pulling them out of the database will unescape them.

Comment: sorry edited my post slightly....I needed something slightly different than what I posted originally

Comment: … and I've rewritten my answer to compensate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using PHP:

For the database, use PDO: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

And for the JSON, use the json methods: http://php.net/json

These handle all the escaping for you.

Comment: I can't install the JSON extension so I'm building json as a string in php and then sending that back. I've realised now that it's actually the special chars breaking my sql query so I need to encode it in php so this doesn't happen.

Comment: Extension? It is part of core! http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/json.requirements.php

Comment: I'm on 5.1.6. Don't think it's part of the core in that version.

Comment: I'm not too sure, but poking around the PHP website indicates that the 5.1 series isn't updated any longer. I'd be really worried about security problems if I was still using it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "not breaking the db INSERT," this should be a completely moot point. You should either be appropriately escaping all user-provided data (eg. [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)) or using [binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Be careful using real_escape_string(). It can open the door insertion attacks. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php . you are better off searching for and replacing characters on your own that way you can dump and invalid strings.